# How to read Beats-per-minute tag of mp3 file in windows store apps C#?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mp3, id3-tag

i am trying to read bpm embedded in mp3 file like this one :

[image: bpm tag im trying to read]

i have tried using

```
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.MusicProperties
```

but it only contains title, singer, etc.
it can't read the bpm i showed before.

im looking into https://taglib.github.io/ they seems not having such function too. 
is there any workaround to this?

Comment: MusicProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync returns a dictionary.  Try asking for "TBPM", the ID3 tag for beats per minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've loaded your music file into a StorageFile, you'll want to place a similar call in your code like this:

`var fileProps = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(null);`

This will get you a list of all the system properties exposed as a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

You can then get the BPM value as follows:

```
if (fileProps.ContainsKey("System.Music.BeatsPerMinute"))
{
    var bpmObj = fileProps["System.Music.BeatsPerMinute"];
    if (bpmObj != null)
    {
        var bpm = bpmObj.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can find a complete list of available file properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx